# ASK demodulation using DSP

Tags: demodulation

I need to implement an ASK (ampliltude shift keying) demodulation using a DSP ( a dsPIC ) and programming in C. Especifically talking, I need to demodulate a signal from a car's key transponder. I already have a circuit of antenna that receive the signal and I already can sample it, but I still have a doubt of how could be the best way, faster and reliable, to filter the signal. 
I was using a FIR filter using Kaiser windowing and 13 taps, but it demanded a lot of processing time and I still have some errors. Is there a better way to do it ?

With my best regards,
Daniel.

Comment: Could you start with analog down conversion? What A/D are you using? How you implement the multiplication for the FIR? What is your sampling rate? Could you implement digital down conversion?

Answer (score 2):

In general, a receiver would consist of these blocks:

1. An analog band-pass filter centered around the carrier frequency.
2. A low-noise amplifier to bring the signal above the receiver's sensitivity.
3. Optionally, an analog intermediate frequency stage.
4. A sampler. You can do bandpass sampling if the carrier frequency is too large for the ADC.
5. In a DSP, implement:

   - Final downconversion if needed.
   - Downsampling to reduce the sampling rate
   - Carrier, frame and symbol synchronization
   - Matched filtering to recover the bits with optimum BER (in the case of ASK with rectangular pulse shaping, the matched filter is just an integrate & dump filter)

I highly recommend that you get and read Telecommunications Breakdown, by Johnson and Sethares, which is available for free (as a draft) from the authors' website: [C. R. Johnson, W. A. Sethares - Telecommunication Breakdown - Concepts of Communication Transmitted via Software-Defined Radio](http://sethares.engr.wisc.edu/telebreak.html).

Comment: Thnak you very much!! Sorry for the delayed answer. I needed to stop the project and now I'm starting again in my free time only.

Comment: I liked your recomendations and  the book reference, I noticed that I was not performing downconversion. I'm performing the sampling at 900Khz and the signal of interest has a 30kHz base band and has a carrier frequency of 125kHz.  The carrier is generated in the own base station that I'm implementing and the transponder modulates it by load modulation. So I was wondering how to do a digital multiplication of the samples by a  cosine wave to perform downconversion.

Comment: @Daniel The trick is to generate a sine wave of the same frequency and phase as the transmitter's. You need to perform carrier synchronization to find the frequency and phase, and then use those to downcovert.

Comment: I'm performing downconversion via sampling. The received signal has a carrier frequency of 125 kHz modulated with a 30kHz that is the signal of interest, so, I sampled the received signal with a tax rate of 62,5kHz that is the half of the frequency of the carrier.